# How to assert "Content-Type" set by SpringFramework's org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one GET Rest-endpoint in my sample app which returns some data based on criteria it can also return null if no data is available with HTTP status as `204` else `200 OK` if data is available.

```
@GetMapping("/homepage")
    public ResponseEntity getHomePageCollections(@RequestHeader(value = HEADER_APP_TOKEN) String headerAppToken) {
        CollectionObject homepageCollections = null;
        String errorMessage = null;
        HttpStatus httpStatus;
        try {
            homepageCollections = collectionService.getHomePageCollections();
            if (nonNull(homepageCollections)) {
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
                LOGGER.info("{} Response Status from CollectionController -- getHomePageCollections !! {}", TRANSACTION_SUCCESS_CODE, TRANSACTION_SUCCESS);
            } else {
                httpStatus = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
                LOGGER.info("{} Response Status from CollectionController -- getHomePageCollections !! {}", NO_CONTENT_CODE, NO_CONTENT);
            }
        } // catch logic
        return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(httpStatus == HttpStatus.OK || httpStatus == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT ? homepageCollections : errorMessage);
    }
```

- I have 2 questions, first is how to **assert the content type** is
  set by the controller in my unit test

***Unit Test***

```
@Test
    public void testGetHomePageCollection() {
        when(collectionService.getHomePageCollections()).thenReturn(null);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = collectionController.getHomePageCollections(HEADER_APP_TOKEN);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

- When the **homepageCollections** is null spring auto-sets the content type as **octet-stream**, is there a reason behind it?

Comment: Are you seeing the response with content type octet stream being set? I'm curious since you are setting the content type to application/json regardless of the homepageCollections being null in the controller method.

Comment: This is happening when I am not setting any content type and the `homepageCollections` value is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ContentType` is present in the headers of the response, so you can test the same by accessing it as below:

```
@Test
        public void testGetHomePageCollection() {
            when(collectionService.getHomePageCollections()).thenReturn(null);

            ResponseEntity responseEntity = collectionController.getHomePageCollections(HEADER_APP_TOKEN);
            assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            assertThat(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        }
```